Issue Finding a Variable in a Shiny App on EC2
I have a shiny app on EC2 that is not rendering. The error is this...
enter image description here
When I go to the logs, I get the following errors
enter image description here
But in the code, MyDT is clearly there.
Can anyone help point to what i may be doing wrong

#===============================================================================

message("app: Script Execution Initialized \n")

#===============================================================================
### IMPORT PACKAGES 

message("app: Import Packages \n")

print(.libPaths())

library(shiny)
library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)
library(DT)
library(lubridate)
library(hms)

#===============================================================================
### 

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  MyDT <- reactive({
    
    AbrQuery <- "

      SELECT 
          * 
      FROM SQ_ML_MODEL.dbo.DataSci_ABR_Preds_Vs_Actuals_updated
 
    "
    
    SecretValuesLst <- GetSecret(Debug = TRUE)
    
    print(SecretValuesLst)
    
    print(SecretValuesLst$SERVER)
    
    #===============================================================================
    
    connectionString <- paste0(
      "Driver={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};Server=",SecretValuesLst$SERVER,
      ";Database=",SecretValuesLst$DATABASE,
      ";UID=",SecretValuesLst$UID,
      ";PWD=",SecretValuesLst$PWD, 
      ";TrustServerCertificate=yes;",
      sep="")
    
    DbCon <- RODBC::odbcDriverConnect(connectionString)
    
    print(DbCon)
    
    #===============================================================================
    
    DataOutput <- RODBC::sqlQuery(DbCon, query = AbrQuery)
    
    DataOutput
    
    #===============================================================================
    ### 
    
    message("render_app_data: Prepare Data \n")
    
    # RawAbrData
    
    # str(RawAbrData)
    
    VizAbrData <- melt.data.table(DataOutput[, .(MinuteOfDay,
                                                 AgentCategory,
                                                 Queue,
                                                 Login,
                                                 Tier,
                                                 Abr_Actuals,
                                                 Abr_Preds,
                                                 Abr_Diff)],
                                  id.vars = c("MinuteOfDay",
                                              "AgentCategory"))
    
    VizAbrData
    
    # VizAbrData[, .N, by = variable]
    
    # VizAbrData[variable == "Login"]
    
    VizAbrData[, AsOfDate := as_date(MinuteOfDay)]
    
    # WhichDates <- VizAbrData[order(-AsOfDate)][, unique(AsOfDate)][1:14]
    
    # WhichDates
    
    # VizAbrData <- VizAbrData[AsOfDate %in% WhichDates]
    
    # VizAbrData
    
    VizAbrData$value[is.na(VizAbrData$value)] <- 0
    
    # VizAbrData
    
    library(hms)
    
    VizAbrData[, MinuteOfDay_TIME := as_hms(MinuteOfDay)]
    
    mydat <- VizAbrData
    
    mydat[, AsOfDate := as.Date(AsOfDate)]
    
    mydat[, variable := as.character(variable)]
    
    #WhichDates <- mydat[, .N, by = AsOfDate][order(-AsOfDate)][1:10, AsOfDate]
    
    #WhichVariables <- mydat[, .N, by = variable][order(-variable)][1:10, variable]
    
  })
  
  output$distPlot1 <- renderPlot({
    
    filtered_data_1 <- reactive({
      dplyr::filter(MyDT, 
                    AsOfDate %in% as.Date(input$Date1) & 
                      variable %in% as.character(input$Metric1))
    })
    
    ggplot(data = filtered_data_1(),
           aes(x = MinuteOfDay,
               y = value)) +
      geom_point(stat = "identity", col = "black") +
      geom_line(stat = "identity", linewidth = 1.6, col = "red") + 
      labs(x = "MinuteOfDay", y = input$Metric1) +
      ggtitle(paste0("Time Series: ", input$Metric1, sep = "")) +
      theme(
        plot.title = element_text(size=16, face= "bold", colour= "black", hjust = 0.5, margin = margin(t=10,b=-20)),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size=16, face="bold", colour = "black"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size=14, face="bold", colour = "black"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=14, face="bold", colour = "black"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=14, face="bold", colour = "black"), # bold
        strip.text.x = element_text(size = 14, face="bold", colour = "black" ),
        strip.text.y = element_text(size = 14, face="bold", colour = "black"),
        axis.line.x = element_line(color="black", size = 0.3),
        axis.line.y = element_line(color="black", size = 0.3),
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA)
      )  +
      theme_classic()  
    
  })
}



#=====================================================F==========================
### IMPORT PACKAGES 

message("app: Import Packages \n")

ui <- {
  fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("ABR Dashboard"),
  
  tabsetPanel(      
    
    tabPanel("Time Series",
             sidebarLayout(
               selectInput(inputId = "Date1", 
                           label = "Select Date", 
                           choices = unique(MyDT$AsOfDate)
               ),
               selectInput(inputId = "Metric1",
                           label = "Which Metric",
                           choices = unique(MyDT$variable)
               )
             ),
             
             mainPanel(
               plotOutput("distPlot1")
             )
      ) 
    )
  )
}

#===============================================================================
### IMPORT PACKAGES 

message("app: Import Packages \n")

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)












Have checked the logs and seen if different vaeiables are there

Not sure this has anything to do with EC2. Your shiny app probably will give the same error running locally. You are using the variable MyDT inside your ui but that variable is only defined in your server function. Those variables do not exist outside that function. You need to use function like updateSelectInput in the server to update the UI based on reactive data.

Thanks, for the date input could I just creae a sequence of 15 days abd oass that in. Would make it easier
